# android:how to open the app on clicking on push notification

Tags: android, onclick, push-notification

I have implemented the push notifications using C2DM code in my project. It is showing push notifications But my problem is how to open  the app on clicking on the push notification.

I am doing it like:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(context, BingoDiaryActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("registration_id", registrationId);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, intent, 0);
        notification.setLatestEventInfo(context, "Registration", "Successfully registered",
                pendingIntent);
        notificationManager.notify(0, notification);
```

But it is not working

Can anyone helps me over this?

Thanks

Comment: Just on a hunch. Try a non-zero notification code. .notify(99, notification)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't understand what's wrong with you code, but in my project works this - and clicking on notifier open my app:

```
n.setLatestEventInfo(context, "text", "text", 
        PendingIntent.getActivity(
                context, 
                0,
                context.getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage(context.getPackageName())
                       .putExtra("extra_name", extra), 
                0));
```

Comment: I have edited my question can u now tell me what could be the problem?